# What does the compiler do when I extend class from user defined package?

Tags: java, class, oop, package, extends

I have a user defined package called Drinks,
which has a few classes

```
Drinks
    Water
        Cocoa (extends Water)
        Coffee (extends Water)
    CalculateDrinks
```

after compiling the package, I created a class called **Cappuccino** extending **Coffee**, in default package, which has these classes.

```
Default
    Cappuccino
    TestPackage
```

In **CalculateDrinks**, it has a method called `calculatePrice()` which calculates the sum of every `getPrice()` of Drinks, including **Cappuccino** class (it also has the getPrice method).

I would to ask, how does the `calculatePrice()` method of the **CalculateDrinks** class know about the methods of `getPrice()` in **Cappuccino** class?

Any help would be appreciated. Please tell me if you would like to see the source code.

Edit:
added some essential parts of code

TestPackage.java

```
public class TestPackage{
    public void static main(String[] args){
        Coffee coffee = new Coffee(150);    //that is the price
        Cappuccino cap = new Cappuccino("snowman");

        Drinks drinks = {coffee, cap};
        CalculateDrinks cal = new CalculateDrinks(drinks);
        System.out.println("The total price of all drinks is " + cal.getTotalPrice()); //it should return 350
    }
}
```

CalculateDrinks.java

```
public class CalculateDrinks{
    private int totalPrice;
    private Drinks drinks[];

    CalculateDrinks(Drinks drinks[]){
        this.drinks = drinks;
        calculatePrice();
    }

    public void calculatePrice(){
        for (Drinks drink in drinks){
            totalPrice += drink.getPrice();
        }
    }  

    public int getTotalPrice(){
        return totalPrice;
    }  
}
```

Cappuccino.java

```
public class Cappuccino extends Coffee{
    private String pattern;
    Cappuccino(String pattern){
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }
    public int getPrice(){
        return super.getPrice() + 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] to illustrate?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? How does it know about `Cappuccino`? Unless `TestDrinks` mentions it, or it gets it passed in as a parameter or something like that it won't know about `Cappuccino`. Can you show us how the `TestDrinks` class looks like in your example?

Comment: @FredLarson I have added the source codes, could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in `calculatePrice()` it is calling `getPrice()` method for each drink object separately.

```
public void calculatePrice(){
    for (Drinks drink in drinks){
        totalPrice += drink.getPrice();
    }
}
```

In first step of for loop above; it calls `coffe.getPrice()` because first drink in drinks array is a coffe object.
   In second step; it calls  `getPrice()`of Cappuccino object `cap.getPrice()`.
  You should be aware of `getPrice()`  method is overwritten for each child class and every object is calling its own `getPrice()` method.